# Chain Rule in Matrix Derivatives

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I am trying to understand how matrix derivatives work, focusing myself on the chain rule.

Consider $g(U): \mathbb{R}^{N\text{x}N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $U=f(X) :  \mathbb{R}^{N\text{x}N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N\text{x}N}$

Then applying the chain rule I know that:

$\frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial X_{ij}}=\text{Tr}[(\frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U})^T\frac{\partial U}{\partial X_{ij}}]$

However, what happens if $g(U): \mathbb{R}^{N\text{x}N} \rightarrow ^{N\text{x}N}$. I mean if I have to take the derivative of a matrix w.r.t a matrix. This could appear, for instance, if we have that  $U=f(Z) :  \mathbb{R}^{N\text{x}N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N\text{x}N}$ and $Z=f(X) :  \mathbb{R}^{N\text{x}N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N\text{x}N}$, as on of the steps of the chain rule will involve the derivative of $U$ w.r.t $Z$

Comment: yes totally agree. The thing is that my previous question did not appeared in my profile so I though it was unpublished. That is why I posted it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that $f$ can be expanded as a power series, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
 U &= f(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \beta_kX^k \\
dU &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} X^{j}\,dX\,X^{k-j-1} \\
}$$
You've told us nothing about the $g(U)$ function, but let's also assume you know how to calculate its gradient
$$G = \frac{\partial g}{\partial U} \quad\implies dg = G:dU$$
where the colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\;A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$.

Combining these results yields. 
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= G:\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} X^{j}\,dX\,X^{k-j-1} \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \Big[X^{k-j-1}\,G^T\,X^{j}\Big]^T \,:\,dX \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial X}
 &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \Big[X^{k-j-1}\,G^T\,X^{j}\Big]^T \\
}$$
Thus one can calculate the desired gradient without calculating the 4th-order tensor $\,\frac{\partial U}{\partial X}$

Comment: yes the $g(U)$ function can be something like a trace. Thank's for the answer.

Comment: one more thing, the order of the tensor from $\frac{\partial U}{\partial X}$ is not 3, instead of 4?. By three I mean a 3 dimensional matrix.

Comment: Consider the component form $\frac{\partial U_{ij}}{\partial X_{pq}}$. It's called a 4th order tensor **because** there are 4 free indices $(i,j,p,q)$ each of which ranges from $1\ldots n$ in this case.

Comment: oh perfect, thank you. But when using a computer it can be stored in a 3D array, right?

Comment: I think you missed the point of my post. There is no need to compute **_any_** higher-order tensors. The LHS is $\frac{\partial g}{\partial X}$, which is a matrix, as are all the terms on the RHS (except the $\beta_k$ scalar coefficients). And for common functions, the gradient is often much simpler than the generic result given above.

Comment: yes, I understood. I mean if I wish to do it. Just as a curiosity on the data structure that would be needed.